# R converts strings into numbers using rownames()

Tags: r, matrix

I have a numerical matrix "test" like this"

```
 [1,] 474.00 478.81 468.25 474.98    474.98
 [2,] 463.25 470.00 454.12 468.22    468.22
 [3,] 456.47 466.50 452.58 457.35    454.70
 ...
```

and want to assign `rownames`, which are strings of dates (stored in variable a `names`).

```
> names
 [1] "2013-02-08" "2013-02-07" "2013-02-06" ...
```

when I invoke the rowname function on my matrix, the strings are converted to numbers, which I don't understand. Does someone know a solution that would preserve the strings in names as row names?`enter code here`

```
rownames(test) <- names


15744 474.00 478.81 468.25 474.98    474.98
15743 463.25 470.00 454.12 468.22    468.22
15742 456.47 466.50 452.58 457.35    454.70
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `rownames(test) <- as.character(names)`

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly fine and solved my problem! If you have some time I would very much appreciate it if you could explain to me why this happened, i.e., where the numbers, such as 15744, came from.

Comment: As pointed out by @Twitch, they are the numbers of days since January 1st, 1970. Try `unclass(names)` in the console. Dates are stored as numeric values, with a special class. When you type `names` in the console, R uses the function `print.Date` to transform them to strings - only for printing. That's why you thought you had strings.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to put this as a reply to your comment, but I think those numbers are based upon a difference in dates.  By default, when R detects a date input, it is represented as the number of days since 1970-01-01, with negative values for earlier dates.

See: http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html

EDIT: Just as a test, I took your first input (February 8th, 2013) and calculated the difference between it and January 1st, 1970, and I do get 15,744 days which matches your rowname.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you so much. I didn't know about the "ifference between it and January 1st, 1970", this explains a lot!